# What is the rate of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, sequences-and-series, gm.general-mathematics

How quickly does the series defined by $$x_0 = 0,  \ x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^2+1}{2}$$ converge to $1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting $x_n = 1+y_n$, we have $y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{y_n^2}{2}$. There is a standard method for analyzing recursions of the form $y_{n+1} = y_n+O(y_n^2)$. A good introduction is chapter 8.4 in de Bruijn's [Asymptotic Methods in Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=_tnwmvHmVwMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I'll do the first terms of the expansion for you. Set $z_n = 1/y_n$. Then 
$$z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{z_n^{-1}+z_n^{-2}/2} = z_n - 1/2 + O(1/z_n). \quad (\ast)$$
Since $x_n \to 1^{-}$, we have $y_n \to 0^{-}$ and $z_n \to - \infty$. Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $|z_{n+1} - (z_n-1/2)| < \epsilon$ for $n$ large enough and we deduce $z_n = - n/2 (1+o(1))$. Reversing our substitutions, $x_n = 1-2(1+o(1))/n$.

We can then deduce tighter bounds by "bootstrapping", plugging our previous bounds in $(\ast)$ to give
$$z_{n+1} = z_n - 1/2 + O(1/n)$$
and thus
$$z_{n} = -n/2+O(\log n).$$
Taking more terms in the Taylor series $(\ast)$, and bootstrapping repeatedly, we can get an asymtopic series in powers of $n^{-1}$ and $\log n$.